# excel chart different spaces between values on OX

Tags: excel, charts

trying to make line chart using data

```
X Y
1 12
3 34
5 56
6 68
9 79
14 98
```

is it possible to make different spacec on the horrizontal axis?
because now there are same between 1 and 3, 9 and 14 etc..

Comment: Tim - You should have made this an answer, not merely a comment. I'll do so and give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Williams stated in his comment, which he should have made into a full-fledged answer:

Use an Excel XY (Scatter) chart. A line chart treats X values as non-numeric labels, while the XY chart treats both X and Y as continuous numeric variables. The lines and markers in XY and Line charts can be formatted the same.

Answer (score -1):

To create a bar chart with differently spaced bars, insert empty rows between your x, y pairs so that the spacing of the data in the rows reflects the distance between the x points. For example, if the [1, 12] pair is in cells A1:B1, place the [3, 34] pair two rows down, in cells A3:B3; [5, 56] would go in A5:B5, etc.

This may produce bars that look too narrow. You can increase the width of bars by first left-clicking on one of the bars to select them all, and then right-clicking and selecting Format Data Series. The second slider in Series Options will change the bar width for the chart.